# style border and width issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have the following div style

```
.myDivStyle{
    width: 0px;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 1;
    top: 0;
    overflow-x: hidden;
}
```

which is applied to my `div`

```
<div id="myDiv" class="myDivStyle">...</div>
```

which looks perfect, and the following script returns 0px, again perfect.

```
alert($("#myDiv").css("width"));
```

But if I add a border to that style such as :

```
border: 1px solid #cccccc;
```

then there is a small 2px wide bod on the screen, and the js code above return a width of 2px.

How can I get the bordered div to not be visible on the screen and return a 0px width?
The show/hide of the div is controlled by javascript.
I know I can use `display:none;` and turn it on again with the javascript but I want to see if it can be done by adjusting the style?

```js
alert($("#myDiv").css("width"));
```

```css
.myDivStyle {
  width: 0px;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  top: 0;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="myDiv" class="myDivStyle">...</div>
```

Comment: Try this: change your border to  `outline: 1px solid #cccccc`

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/innerwidth/

Comment: Try to set on your css: border: 1px solid transparent, and then with your other changes in js - change it to something else.

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

`Box-sizing: border-box;`

So that your width of your css width also controls your border.

For the Javascript try using:
`$(id).innerWidth();` or `$(id).outerWidth();`
and see what fits your expectations.

Comment: That still leaves a 2px wide line on the screen.

Answer (score 0):

You can use outline style. Read here for different between outline and border
From: https://www.tutorialrepublic.com/css-tutorial/css-outline.php

> - Outlines do not take up space, because they always placed on top of the box of the element which may cause them to overlap other elements
>     on the page.
> - Unlike borders, outlines won't allow us to set each edge to a different width, or set different colors and styles for each edge. An
>     outline is the same on all sides.
> - Outlines don't have any impact on surrounding elements apart from overlapping.
> - Unlike borders, outlines don't change the size or position of the element.
> - Outlines may be non-rectangular.